# iOS Auto-Layout UILabel wrapping

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to get my subtitle label to wrap, but it always remains one line with truncated text. I have it so the subtitle has a top constraint of 5px to the title/SignIn label, and 20px to the separator.

I've been working with Content Hugging and Compression Resistance but I haven't been able to figure it out.

If I remove the bottom constraint, the label becomes 3 lines as desired, but overlaps the separator (i.e. the content doesn't get pushed down).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What do you have in the attributes inspector for number of lines and line break style?

Comment: I have "numberOfLines = 0" && "line break style = Truncate Tail"

Comment: you need to change line break style to word wrapping

Comment: Changing it to word wrap still shows as 1 line, content is not pushed down, and rest of label (i.e. lines 2-3) are clipped

Comment: it's pushed down, but you will not see it, because constraint's priority is greater than label's content hugging priority and your label's frame remains same.

Comment: change `Bottom Space to: separator` constraint needs have `greater than or equal` relation to `5`.

Comment: Hi Igor ... sorry, why does it need ">= 5" ... ?

Comment: show full view controller image.

Comment: You could always just add a `>=` height constraint of lets say 15 (or whatever your font size is). This will ensure your height constraint having a priority of 1000 and will always expand depending on the size of the text (I find compression resistance scary). It will work as expected provided the `numberOfLines` is 0 and `lineBreak` is word wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set lines to 0. Then enlarge the label to fit in the required lines of code i.e, increase the height of the label on storyboard. Then set the height constraint of the label from the pin menu to that height.

Comment: Since the view is quite complex (i.e. has many elements), this would require me to move everything down ... yes/no?

Comment: let the bottom constraint be as it is and just set the height to accommodate 3 lines, say set it to 60, and click on update frames

Comment: Marking as the correct answer because it is probably the solution for others not knowing about `numberOfLines`. I did have it set in my scenario though. #RestartXcode

Answer (score 0):

So, auto updating my project's settings and restarting Xcode/Simulator had something to do with it!

Everything seems to be working now (with the following settings for the subtitle):

- Content hugging has been set to: h=251 & v=251
- Content compression resistance has been set to: h=750 & v=750
- Number of Lines has been set to: 0
- Line Break Mode has been set to: Truncate Tail
- "Bottom space to separator" constraint has been set to: Equals 20
- "Top space to sign in label" constraint has been set to: Equals 5